# Do i need to set up SPN for SQL Server

Tags: 2013, sql-server, kerberos, sharepoint-farm, setspn

We have already set up our SharePoint farm. We would like to configure kerberos and hence create SPN's. At this point should we go ahead and create SPN's for SQl server also or can it be skipped?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create the spn for the sql server. You need at least two spn. 1 for the sql instance with port noand 1 with sql server fqdn with port number.

http://www.widriksson.com/sharepoint-2013-kerberos-configuration/